# How to use values of map function in other functions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to use data returned by a map method into another function.

Here is the route schema:

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    Location: {
      from: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
      to: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        required: true,
      },
    },
    busId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Bus",
      required: true,
    },
    date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    departureTime: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    arrivalTime: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

and here is the booking schema and in booking table routeId is embedded:

```
const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  routeId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Route",
    required: true,
  },
  passengers: [
    {
      name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      gender: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      age: { type: Number, required: true, trim: true },
    }],
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  bookingDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fare: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  seats: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true,
  },
  departureDetails: [
    {
      city: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      time: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      date: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    },
  ],
  arrivalDetails: [
    {
      city: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      location: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      time: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
      date: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    },
  ],
},{
    timestamps:true
});
```

Here is the map function method:

```
router.get("/trip/single", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.query.from || !req.query.to || !req.query.date) {
    return res.send({
      error: "Please enter the data to get the trip",
    });
  }
  const { from, to, date } = req.query;

  const routes = await Route.find({
    "Location.from": from,
    "Location.to": to,
     "date": date.toString(),
  });

  const matchedBus = await routes.filter(() =>{
    return Route.busId === routes._id
  });

  const bookings = await Booking.find({
    routeId: { $in: matchedBus.map((matchedBus) => matchedBus._id)  },
  });
  console.log(bookings);
  const busIdWithSeatsObj = {};
  var busData = matchedBus.map(data => data)
  console.log(busData);
```

This busData console is returning this data:

```
[
  {
    Location: {
      from: new ObjectId("6295f0986f9e32990d8b3488"),
      to: new ObjectId("6295f0c06f9e32990d8b348b")
    },
    _id: new ObjectId("6295f12c6f9e32990d8b348e"),
    busId: new ObjectId("6295f0836f9e32990d8b3485"),
    date: '2022-06-02',
    departureTime: 11,
    arrivalTime: 6.3,
    createdAt: 2022-05-31T10:42:52.785Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-05-31T10:42:52.785Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Now I want to use only busId and date only in the function below:

```
for (let i = 0; i < matchedBus.length; i++) {
    let currentBusSeats = [];
    const busBookings = bookings.filter((booking) => {
      return (
        //Want to use date and busId data in here
        //someData === date.toString() &&
        //someData === matchedBus[i]._id
      );
    });
    console.log(busBookings);
    busBookings.forEach(() => {
      currentBusSeats = [...currentBusSeats, ...Booking.seats];
    });
    busIdWithSeatsObj[matchedBus[i]._id] = currentBusSeats;
  }

  res.status(200).send({ routes, matchedBus, busIdWithSeatsObj });
});
```

How can I do that to get the result?

Comment: @chridam Question updated.

Answer (score -1):

var busData = matchedBus.map(data => data
'use your for loop inside data and you can get you _id value by data._id'
)

Comment: Can you show me with an example?